Images in Tkinter Grid Layout Overlapping
I'm working on a Tkinter app that displays images of cats in a grid-like layout. My goal is to place the images alternately on the left and right sides of the window, stacking them vertiacaly. However, the images are not appearing in the expected positions.
Here is the code I'm using:
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
import os
import gettingimg2 as img

img.get_titles_and_images("cats", 10)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Cat of the Day")
root.geometry("400x900")

images = []

y_position = 70
count = 0



def closing():
    count = 1
    while count < 11:
        os.remove("C:/Users/User/Desktop/cats/cutecat" + str(count) + ".jpg")
        count += 1
    root.destroy()
    
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", closing)

for i in range(10):

    xcount = 10
    swich = False
    if i == 1 or i == 3 or i == 5 or i == 7 or i == 9 :
        xcount = 200

    image_path = f"C:/Users/User/Desktop/cats/cutecat{i + 1}.jpg"
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    max_width, max_height = 190, 140
    image.thumbnail((max_width, max_height), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)

    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    label = tk.Label(root, image=photo)

    label.place(x=xcount, y=y_position)
    if count == 2 or count == 4 or count == 6 or count == 8 or count == 10:
        y_position += 150

    images.append(photo)
    count += 1
    print("cutecat" + str(i + 1), "x =" + str(xcount), "y=" + str(y_position))

root.mainloop()


The images should alternate between the left (x=10) and right (x=200) sides, and the y_position should increase every second image to stack them vertically. However, the images are not displaying as expected.
Here are the logs from my program, which show the coordinates where each image is placed:
cutecat1 x=10 y=70
cutecat2 x=200 y=70
cutecat3 x=10 y=220
cutecat4 x=200 y=220
cutecat5 x=10 y=370
cutecat6 x=200 y=370
cutecat7 x=10 y=520
cutecat8 x=200 y=520
cutecat9 x=10 y=670
cutecat10 x=200 y=670



I expected each image to be placed at the correct x and y positions, alternating between the left and right sides and increasing the y position by 150 pixels every second image. I already tried making the window bigger.

You are calculating y_position after the label.place() line that uses it - so it's using the Y value intended for the previous image.


My goal is to place the images alternately on the left and right sides
of the window, stacking them vertically

expected each image to be placed at the correct x and y positions, alternating >>between the left and right sides and increasing the y position by 150 pixels every >>second image


The problem can be fixed.
Online 45, change this:
l = tk.Label(root, image=image)
            

to:
l = tk.Label(root, image=photo) #<== image-> photo

            

On line 47, change this:
if count == 2 or count == 4 or count == 6 or count == 8 or count == 10:

To:
if count == 1 or count == 3 or count == 5 or count == 7 or count == 9:

Screenshot:


There is another way to do looping.     for i in range(10, 400, 200):
for r in range(70, 820, 150):

Don't use place(), it confuses even the most experienced programmers. Use grid() instead:
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
import os
import gettingimg2 as img

img.get_titles_and_images("cats", 10)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Cat of the Day")
root.geometry("400x900")

images = []

y_position = 70
count = 0


def closing():
    count = 1
    while count < 11:
        os.remove("C:/Users/User/Desktop/cats/cutecat" + str(count) + ".jpg")
        count += 1
    root.destroy()


root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", closing)


for i in range(10):
    image_path = f"C:/Users/User/Desktop/cats/cutecat{i + 1}.jpg"
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    max_width, max_height = 190, 140
    image.thumbnail((max_width, max_height), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)

    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    images.append(photo)

column = 0
row = 0

for photo in images:
    l = tk.Label(root, image=photo)
    l.grid(column=column, row=row)
    if column == 2:
        column = 0
        row += 1
    else:
        column += 1
    count += 1

root.mainloop()

By using grid(), you can just calculate if the column is already 6, and if it is then change the row number and reset the column number.

Note that OP wants 2 columns, not 7 for your case. Also it is not necessary to have two for loops, just one is enough.

The exact same bug occurs again: the left row is 1 row too high, and cutecat3 overlaps with cutecat1.

@Kilian I'm sorry if I misunderstood something, can you please tell me which image is the one you want it to display?

@LukeL, thank you for your answer. I mentioned 'vertically,' but your code made it horizontal. When I tried to change it, as soon as it worked, I got the same bug as with place. But thank you, because I learned to make GUIs with grid instead of place.

@Kilian Sorry I wasn't able to change it immediately, but I just edited the code to place it vertically. Please check out :)
